# Unix command to replace string after a matched pattern

Tags: unix

Sample file:

```
unit xyz(
    ty=j;
    sc=abc.sh;
    path=/home/script/env;
prm=-j" Acknowledgement";
"abc";
"def";
    prm="total_accounts";
prm=-j" Hierarchy";
safa
)
```

I need a Unix command to replace the phrases as below after the pattern **prm=-j"** whenever it appears in the file without changing the indentation of the existing file.

Replaced lines should be:

**prm=-j" Acknowledgement_V";**

**prm=-j" Hierarchy_V";**

Answer (score 0):

use sed command and try.

Ex:

```
$sed 's/unix/linux/' file_name.txt
```

above command will find **unix** keyword and replace first found word to **linux** in line by line.

for more info check [click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/)